# PHP/Laravel parent class variable is null when calling from different controllers

Tags: php, laravel, parent

*Parent Class:*

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class RequestVariables {

    protected static $keys_tour;

    public static function init() {

    self::$keys_tour = array_flip(['tour_type', 'city_from']);

    }

}
```

*Child Class:*

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class PreviousVersions extends RequestVariables {

       public static function createVersion ($tour) {

            dd(parent::$keys_tour);

  }
}
```

*When I call `PreviousVersions::createVersion()` from 1st controller:*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;    

use App\Services\PreviousVersions;

use App\Tour;

class Tours2Controller extends Controller

{

    public static function PreProcess($tour)

    { 

        PreviousVersions::createVersion($tour);
    }

}
```

*it outputs what's expected:*

```
array:2 [
  "tour_type" => 0
  "city_from" => 1 ]
```

*but when I execute the same function in another controller:*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Tour;

use App\Services\PreviousVersions;


class BookingController extends Controller {

    public function booking($tour)

    {

      PreviousVersions::createVersion($tour);

    }

}
```

*it outputs* 'null'

I can't see what's different between my controllers causing different results when calling the same method. Can somebody tell me why it outputs 'null' in the 2nd case?

If you need more information, please ask.

Comment: Who is calling `init()`?

Comment: @ Camilo could you be more specific, please?

Comment: The `$keys_tour` property is being set inside the `init()` method of the `RequestVariables` class. You will need to call that method to set the value of `$keys_tour`.

Comment: @ Camilo when call createVersion method from Tours2Controller, I don't call "init()" and it works. Why?

Comment: Are you sure is not being called somewhere else?

Comment: @ Camilo, you're right. Before calling createVersion I called another method from another child class of RequestVariable and there I nad "    RequestVariables::init();". I've added "RequestVariables::init();" in the createVersions method and now it works!

Comment: @Camillo, maybe you add the answer and I choose it as "correct answer"?)

Comment: Added a proper answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: Don't forget accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$keys_tour` property is being set inside the `init()` method of the `RequestVariables` class.

You can solve it by calling `RequestVariables::init()` inside the `createVersions()` method:

```
public static function createVersion ($tour)
{
    RequestVariables::init();
}
```

Or using the `parent` keyword:

```
public static function createVersion ($tour)
{
    parent::init();
}
```